# [RESOLVED]How to cancel "bootstrap modal" exit behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I need to validate data (eg. fill up all of the fields in the form) before users intend to close the modal via close-button or backdrop-area.

If it's valid then let the exit process going otherwise cancel it.

```
<Modal show={isShow} keyboard={false} >
  <Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Title>Profile</Modal.Title>
    <CloseButton onClick={onClose} />
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    {...}
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

It's possible to do this in React?

---

## Solution

According to [Modal#onHide](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/api/Modal#onHide) description, I listen to the `onHide` then validate data before close it.

```
const onModalHide = () => {
  if (validateData()) setIsShow(false);
};
```

```
<Modal show={isShow} onHide={onModalHide} >
  <Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Title>Profile</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    {...}
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **You will need to manually select the modal id and listen on `hide.bs.modal` event**

**You are using bootstrap so probably already import jquery so:**

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
   if (!validated) return e.preventDefault() 
})
```

**Or with js:**

```
document.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    if (event.target.id == 'myModal') {
      if (!validated) return e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your key information(`hide.bs.modal`) that points me to find [the correct way](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/api/Modal#onHide) to deal with this issue!

Comment: Although it works, this is not how you want to do things in react. That is not the React way..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `onClose` is changing the `isShow` state.

In that case just check whether or not you want to close the modal:

```
const onClose = () => {
  if(validateFormLogic()) //this is where you validate your form
    setIsShow(false);
}

<Modal show={isShow} keyboard={false} >
  <Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Title>Profile</Modal.Title>
    <CloseButton onClick={onClose} />
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    {...}
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

You decide when to close the modal, not bootstrap nor react.

Comment: You're right! For the close button, I just should validate data in the `onClose` function!